# scanner.hasNext() results in an infinite loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I have a piece of code which should read input word by word and add the length of the word to an ArrayList recursively (for a school exercise).

I wrote this method:

```
ArrayList<Integer> wordLengths = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// ...
private void readWords() {
    // read a word, if there are more words, read the next word
    this.wordLengths.add(this.scanner.next().length());

    if (this.scanner.hasNext()) {
        readWords();
    }
}
```

When I call this method, it keeps asking for new words. It won't stop the (recursive) loop. Why is this happening? `this.scanner.hasNext()` should only be true when there's a next word in the input so it should stop when there is no other word.

Comment: What input do you provide?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "it keeps asking for new words"? I'd add that using recursion here is a very odd approach... you'd normally use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis System.in, console input from eclipse

Comment: @JonSkeet I know, that's why I added (for a school exercise) What I mean is that the readWords() method never stops calling itself. Even when all the words are read.

Comment: "for a school exercise" doesn't automatically mean "we have to use recursion". It would have been clearer if you'd stated that.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sorry if it was a bit confusing, that is what I meant though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System.in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) is an input stream. It is never closed, so it will always return true for #hasNext()

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind next time! I'll select your answer when I'm able to unless a better one shows up.

Comment: Not quite true.  `hasNext()` can return `false` if an end-of-file condition on the input is reached.  I just tried it on a Windows system and I got the program to work (in a Command Prompt window) by typing control-Z and then <Enter>.  Redirecting standard input works too.  This may be platform-dependent, and I don't know whether Eclipse's console input would be able to trigger an end-of-file condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl+Z`(+Enter) in Windows or `Ctrl+D` in Unix to send EOF and terminate input stream

Comment: Well, I haven't used Eclipse for years but I assume that you can just do it in console view (place your cursor in console view, press Ctrl+Z and then Enter)